# Django: how do I implement a functional delete button for an object where the view loops thru api request data?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Basically I have this little weather application from a tutorial I followed and am trying to extend functionality. The app will take a city input POST request from user, call openweather api, loop through all cities then appends that openweather api (dict) data into a python list. The list is then called by 'context' variable to render the data in template. I am trying to add a functional delete button to each city shown on the page, sounds easy but since the view is making an api call and putting it in a list, that data doesn't have a city.id. This results in a NoReverseMatch error in my template.

I tried to split the view up into parts. If I segregate the `cities = City.objects.all()` and just set `context = {'cities': cities}`, my `city_delete` function works properly with the city.id. I was able to delete the City from the template. But am not able to render the api data into the same bootstrap card because of the context dict.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import requests
from environs import Env
from .models import City, Words
from .forms import CityForm  

env = Env()
env.read_env()
WEATHER_API_KEY = env.str('WEATHER_API_KEY')



# Create city delete function (implemented in indext_test.html)
def delete_city(request, city_id):
    city = City.objects.get(pk=city_id)
    city.delete()
    return redirect('index_test')
 
# Create main weather page view for index.html (works fine with no delete function)
def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=faa30bca64456bb8655bdda8f22865c3'
    cities = City.objects.all().order_by('name')
    weather_data = []

    if request.method == 'POST': # only true if form is submitted
        form = CityForm(request.POST) # add actual request data to form for processing
        form.save() # will validate and save if validated
    form = CityForm()

    for city in cities:
        city_weather = requests.get(url.format(city.name)).json() # request the API data and convert the JSON to Python data types

        weather = {
                'city': city,
                'temperature': city_weather['main']['temp'],
                'description': city_weather['weather'][0]['description'],
                'icon': city_weather['weather'][0]['icon'],
                }
        weather_data.append(weather) # add the data of the current city to our list

        context = {'weather_data': weather_data, 'form': form}

        return render(request, 'weather/index.html', context) # returns the index template



#=================================================================================================
#=====================          TESTING          =================================================


# Testing (working) delete function with basic word in db
def delete_word(request, word_id):
    word = Words.objects.get(pk=word_id)
    word.delete()
    return redirect('word_page')

# Testing (working) delete function with basic word in db
def word_view(request):
    words = Words.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'weather/word_page.html', {'words': words})


# Create test weather page view for index_test.html (does not work with delete function added)
def index_test(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=faa30bca64456bb8655bdda8f22865c3'
    cities = City.objects.all().order_by('name')
    db_cities = City.objects.all().order_by('name')

    weather_data = []

    if request.method == 'POST': # only true if form is submitted
        form = CityForm(request.POST) # add actual request data to form for processing
        form.save() # will validate and save if validated
    form = CityForm()

    for city in cities:
        city_weather = requests.get(url.format(city.name)).json() # request the API data and convert the JSON to Python data types

     
        weather = {
                'city': city,
                'temperature': city_weather['main']['temp'],
                'description': city_weather['weather'][0]['description'],
                'icon': city_weather['weather'][0]['icon'],     
                }
        weather_data.append(weather) # add the data of the current city to our list

    context = {'weather_data': weather_data, 'form': form}

    return render(request, 'weather/index_test.html', context) # returns the index template

# Random about page view for <a> placeholder
class AboutPageView(TemplateView): 
    template_name = 'about.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='home'), # path for index view (working)

        path('index_test', views.index_test, name='index_test'), # path for index test (failed)
        path('delete_city/<city_id>/', views.delete_city, name='delete_city'), # delete city url

        path('word_page/', views.word_view, name='word_page'), 
        path('delete_word/<word_id>/', views.delete_word, name='delete_word'), # test word delete (working)
        path('about/', views.AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
        
        ]
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'weather/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<body style='background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, black)'>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column is-offset-4 is-4">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="field has-addons">
                            <div class="control is-expanded">
                                {{ form.name }} 
                            </div>
                            <div class="control">
                                <button class="button is-info">
                                    Add City
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column is-offset-4 is-4">
                    {% for weather in weather_data %}
                    <div class="box">
                        <article class="media">
                            <div class="media-left">
                                <figure class="image is-50x50">
                                    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{ weather.icon }}.png" alt="Image">
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-content">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <p>
                                    <span class="title">{{ weather.city }}</span>
                                        <br>
                                        <span class="subtitle">{{ weather.temperature }}</span>
                                        <br> {{ weather.test }}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href='{% url "delete_city" city.id %}' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Delete</a>


                        </article>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--footer class="footer">
    </footer-->
</body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self): # Show the actual city name on admin dashboard
        return self.name

    class Meta: # Show the plural of cities instead of citys
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'


# Testing word delete function
class Words(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I copied the entire `index.html` code into `index_test.html` for testing and wired it up with the `index_test(request)` view.

In the html file, I am primarily messing with lines `{% for weather in weather_data %}` and also `<a href='{% url "delete_city" city.id %}' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Delete</a>`

As is, when I try to load `index_test.html` I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/index_test

Django Version: 3.0.14
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'weather']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/user/Desktop/First_Program/Django_Projects/weather_application/weather/templates/weather/base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'delete_city' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete_city/(?P<city_id>[^/]+)/$']
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 : <head>
   4 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   5 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   6 :     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   7 :     <title>What's the weather like?</title>
   8 :     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
   9 :     
   10 : </head>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/First_Program/Django_Projects/weather_application/weather/views.py", line 106, in index_test
    return render(request, 'weather/index_test.html', context) # returns the index template
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/weather_application-HkT3FMgS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /index_test
Exception Value: Reverse for 'delete_city' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete_city/(?P<city_id>[^/]+)/$']
```

When I change the `<a href='{% url "delete_city" city.id %}' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Delete</a>` to `<a href='{% url "about" %}` (as a placeholder) I don't get this error.

When I change `{% for weather in weather_data %}` to `{% for city in cities %}` I can loop thru the cities in the DB and properly delete them from the template. But no api data being rendered.

The more I try to explain this the closer I feel to solving this issue. I am sure it has something to do with the way the `city_id` is being confused in the `delete_city/<city_id>/` URL because of the api data in context. Maybe I will sleep on it and come back with a fresh mind. Either way thank you in advance to anybody who reads.

So my question is how can I get this delete function to take the id of the actual City in my DB and not throw an exception from the loop in the view?

API data example:

```
MIAMI CITY WEATHER: {'coord': {'lon': -80.1937, 'lat': 25.7743}, 'weather': [{'id': 802, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'scattered c
louds', 'icon': '03n'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 76.41, 'feels_like': 77.47, 'temp_min': 72, 'temp_max': 78.03, 'pressure
': 1014, 'humidity': 79}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 3, 'deg': 140, 'gust': 13}, 'clouds': {'all': 29}, 'dt': 1667627848, 
'sys': {'type': 2, 'id': 2009435, 'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1667647905, 'sunset': 1667687818}, 'timezone': -14400, 'id': 4164138, 'n
ame': 'Miami', 'cod': 200}
```

Comment: Where is this `"city":city` you defined in `weather` dictionary of `index` view from where it is coming? Does the `delete_word` view works perfectly?

Comment: `"city:city"` comes from `for loop` inside  `index(request)` and comes from API data I will add example,  and yes `delete_word` works perfect

Comment: `{% url "delete_city" weather.city.id %}`?

Comment: Eureka! Aaron that fixed it, thank you so much for your response. Just brilliant!